# htaccess conditional rewrite for domain vs subdomain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have looked through a good number of code examples, but I am unable to solve this particular problem with htaccess. I need two rule-sets:

RULE-1: Respond to requests for {domain.com or www.domaincom}
+ Redirect to folder domain.com/main/ but do this without showing path
+ Rewrite all http:// to http://www

RULE-2: Re-direct all sub-domain requests (xyz.domain.com) to wordpress instance under folder domain.com/wordpress/, again without revealing path.

To re-phrase, the www/domian.com folder will have two sub-folders (main and wordpress) that should be served depending on which URI (domain or sub-domain) has been requested. What I have managed thus far:

```
## RULE-1 correctly redirects to folder, does not rewrite to www.domain.com
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# RULE-2 (WP) Enabling this rule breaks RULE-1 and domain.com gets directed to wordpress.
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: You should really explain what your current code does wrongly.

Comment: Wain: Thanks for the remark.
RULE-1 does not rewrite "domain.com" to "www.domain.com", but otherwise works.
RULE-2 when enabled: over-rides RULE-1, so that domain.com requests end up being served by wordpress folder and not by main folder.
* wp-admin is not reachable (cannot login)
* folder sturcture is not transparent but visible in address bar (http://domain.com/wordpress/)
Hope this clarifies.